# Actualizar relaciones entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estoy presentando un problema ya que yo tengo una conexión de mi proyecto .net frameworks a sqlserver por medio de entity framework. Y creé una nueva tabla con relación a una tabla existente pero a la hora de actualizar el modelo no me carga la relación el diagrama del modelo.

Esta relación que mencionó no se ve en el entity.

Muchas gracias.

Borre la tabla en el modelo del entity y la volví a cargar pero no sé actualiza la relación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen muestro como no se cargo la relacion.

Sin embargo en sql ya la tengo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si usas migraciones?

Comment: que usas model first, code first o database first

Comment: No puedo usar migraciones ya que es una bd de produccion y me genera desconfianza realizarlo desde ahi.

Comment: Utilizo model first